# How do I open an external EXE file inside of C?

Tags: c, windows, exe

How do I open an external EXE file from inside C?  I'm trying to write a C program that opens Notepad, and some other applications and I am stuck.
Thanks for putting up with my noob level of C ;p

Comment: You might want to look into making a win32 api call to _exec or similar.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `system("notepad");` which will open the notepad executable. Please note that the path to the executable should be part of `PATH` variable or the full path needs to be given to the `system` call.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.. Am I missing a library or something?

Comment: Can you please try including this header file `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: It is in there by default.

Comment: Did you try with a standard application or some specific application of yours? If it's the latter, can you confirm if the path to the variable is either full present in the system call or is part of `PATH` variable?

Answer (score 0):

CreateProcess or ShellExecute is the Windows way of starting another process. You will need to #include  to see their definitions

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
   STARTUPINFOW siStartupInfo; 
   PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo; 
   memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo)); 
   memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo)); 
   siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo); 

   if (CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"), 
                        NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
                        0, NULL, NULL, 
                        &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo)) 
   { 
        /* This line waits for the process to finish. */ 
        /* You can omit it to keep going whilst the other process runs */ 
       dwExitCode = WaitForSingleObject(piProcessInfo.hProcess, (SecondsToWait * 1000)); 
   } 
   else 
   { 
       /* CreateProcess failed */ 
       iReturnVal = GetLastError(); 
   } 
   return 0;
}
```